# Quarter on Quarter/ Month on Month analysis in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, finance

I've loans data and I want to compare sales in different years based on quarter or month

My data looks like this

```
disbursementdate | amount | product | cluster
2017-01-01       | 1000   | HL      | West
2018-02-01       | 1000   | PL      | East
```

So After querying, I'd ideally want the result to look like this

```
 Quarter | 2017 | 2018
   Q1    | 1000 | 0
   Q2    | 100  | 1000
```

Similarly, it can be done for a monthly analysis as well

I'm not averse to storing data in a different format either ... can split date in different field like month quarter year

I'm struggling with query

Comment: In sample data, there is no value for Q2 of 2018? Add some sample data and exact output from sample data to get it understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select quarter(disbursementdate) as quarter,
       sum(case when year(disbursementdate) = 2017 then amount else 0 end) as amount_2017,
       sum(case when year(disbursementdate) = 2018 then amount else 0 end) as amount_2018
from 
group by quarter(disbursementdate) ;
```

If you wanted `year`/`quarter` on separate rows, you would do:

```
select year(disbursementdate) as year, quarter(disbursementdate) as quarter,
       sum(amount)
from 
group by year(disbursementdate), quarter(disbursementdate) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    SELECT YEAR(disbursementdate) as _year, quarter, SUM(amount)
    FROM
       (
      SELECT disbursementdate, QUARTER(disbursementdate) as quarter, 
       amount,  product, cluster
       FROM mytable
   ) AS sub_query
  GROUP BY _year, quarter
```

the format is a bit different but it should be better for the analyses

Comment: Why would anyone use a subquery for this?